# I stuck on startup screen because I put my script on rc3.d and it is infinity while loop

Tags: c, linux, yocto

My script is about open a device when startup.

Actually, I think is not about code error but its about when I put my_app
on /etc/rc3.d/my_app I don't run it in background process that make it stuck on while loop and cant use Ctrl+c / Ctrl+z to cancel it because it run on startup terminal.

Any Idea to interrupt my app to exit the infinity loop ?
- what I think is try to access the data storage directly and disable/remove my symlink my_app on etc/rc3.d but I cant do that.

- my OS is yocto
- my app  starts at runlevel 3

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>     /* File Control Definitions          */
#include <termios.h>   /* POSIX Terminal Control Definitions*/
#include <unistd.h>    /* UNIX Standard Definitions         */
#include <errno.h>     /* ERROR Number Definitions          */
#include <termios.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define BAUDRATE B19200 // 19200 use for input r ,, 115200

unsigned char ClearScreen[] = {254,88};

void usbreset(){
    FILE *fp;
    char *command;
    //char *command2;
    //char boss[100];
    char path[1035];
    //commnad = "sudo su";
    command = (char *) malloc(30);
    //command2 = (char *) malloc(30);
    command ="lsusb | grep 1b3d:012c";
    char command2[100] = "./rest ";


     fp = popen(command,"r"); 

     while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
     //    printf("\n %s", path);
    }
    printf("%zu", strlen(path));

    char final[strlen(path)-1];

          printf("%s\n", path);
          printf("%zu \n", strlen(path));

      int x=0;
      while(x < strlen(path)-1){
        printf("%x ",path[x]);
        final[x] = path[x];
        x++;
      }

        printf("%s\n",final);
        printf("%zu\n",strlen(final) );
    // final is out put of lsusb -t 


   char str[40] = " ";
   strcpy(str,final);
   const char s[2] = " "; // token split
   char *token;
   //char a[22];
   char bus[3] = " ";
   char dev[3] = " ";

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);
   //printf("%c\n", token[0]);
   /* walk through other tokens */
   int count = 0;
   while( token != NULL ) {

      if(count == 1){
        strcpy(bus,token);
      } else if(count == 3){
        strncpy(dev,token,3);
      }

      token = strtok(NULL, s);
      count += 1;      
   }    
   char reset_command[100] = "/dev/bus/usb/";
   strcat(reset_command,bus);
   strcat(reset_command,"/");
   strcat(reset_command,dev);

   strcat(command2,reset_command);

   printf("%s\n", command2 );

   fp = popen(command2,"r"); 

   fclose(fp);

}


int main(){
    //FILE *openfile;
    //openfile = fopen("logfile.txt","r+b");
    int fd;

    FILE *fp;
    char *command;
    char path[16];
    command ="ls /dev/ttyUSB*";
    fp = popen(command,"r");
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {
     //    printf("\n %s", path);
    }
    char final[strlen(path)-1];
    int x=0;
      while(x < strlen(path)-1){
        //printf("%x ",path[x]);
        final[x] = path[x];
        x++;
      }
    fclose(fp);



    struct termios term;
    fd = open(final, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if(fd == 1){
        printf("Error! in Opening ttyUSB0\n");
    }else{
        printf("Device Detected!\n");
        printf("Opening Successfully\n");
    }

    term.c_cflag = BAUDRATE | CS8 | CSTOPB | CLOCAL | CREAD;
    term.c_iflag = 0;
    term.c_oflag = 0;
    term.c_lflag = 0;
    tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
    tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&term);    
    write(fd,ClearScreen,sizeof(ClearScreen));
    //int lcd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    //fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    int err_cnt = 0;

   printf("start\n");
  //return 0;
    while(1){



    char buffer[100];
        ssize_t length = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if(length == -1){
            //printf("Error reading from serial port\n");
            //printf("%zu\n",length);
      printf("%s\n",buffer );
            err_cnt += 1;
            printf("%d\n",err_cnt );
            usbreset();


        }else{
            err_cnt = 0;
            printf("%c", buffer[length]);
        }
        buffer[length] = '\0';
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I yocto a linux distro? Is it still using system-V init scripts?

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi I dont know what it call. I use a bash script to call my binary from the other directory. Is it call system-V ?

Comment: No, but if yocto is a Linux distro you should probably be writing a systemd service instead of a bash script.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi yeah I think I will but now Im stuck and cant get out of this loop so I cant access to main terminal that why I cant manage anything.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi in Yocto you can choose which init system you use (svsvinit, systemd, busybox..)

Comment: JFYI .. yocto is not a Linux distro ..It is nothing but a smart build system.https://www.yoctoproject.org/

Comment: @popro we don't know what is your board, but basically, you will need to reflash it with clean image. Then I suggest you to create a launcher script that will run your app.

Comment: Can I run on level 1 (single user) to remove my script ?
- If I can access to rc1, rc3 will not run when start up and I can use the terminal however I can use only grub v0.97 terminal. Any command to change run level from grub ?
- I cant reflash because It will effect to the other project inside it.

Comment: I know on most Ubuntu flavored linuxes (ubuntu, mint, others), CTRL-ALT-F1 will switch you to a console login.  That is started pretty soon in the boot process, so it might let you login to remove that rc3 script.

Comment: just append the startlevel at the end of kernel commandline arguments

Comment: Boot from a live distro, mount the filesystem and edit rc3

Comment: @stark yeah I try this and its work thanks bros !